# Does python interpreter performing on the fly optimization?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, dynamic-memory-allocation

Let's say for instance I have a list and I want to convert to an `np.array`. A good way (IMHO) would be:

```
my_np_array = np.reshape(my_list,(200,200))
```

If I were a really bad person, I could use:

```
my_np_array = np.array(my_list).reshape(200,200)
```

or even

```
useless_array = np.array(my_list)
useful_array = useless_array/reshape(200,200)
```

Assuming `useless_array` is not mentioned anymore, is the python interpreter able to transform the second and the third statements into the first?

EDIT: I was thinking about the standard 3.7 python interpreter when I asked the question, but I would be interested in any Python interpreter/compiler able to perform optimization.

Comment: I intuitively thought the same, but I was absolutely stunned by optimization by the C++ compiler and node.js interpreter, therefore I wanted to ask. As well, the second statement is a one-line statement, therefore the interpreter might be able to optimize it and avoid allowing memory for useless array.

Comment: @DennisPatterson please check your facts. The python interpreter compiles the source code to bytecode and executes this bytecode. (nb : this doesn't actually imply any optimization happens at this stage - doing runtime optimisations a dynamic language like Python is not trivial...).

Comment: @ThéophilePace you can use the `dis` module to check the generated opcodes for your different code snippets.

Comment: @DennisPatterson the way you expressed it implies that the runtime would directly interpret the source code line by line which is not the case. Also the generated bytecode is not necessarily a strict one to one mapping of the source code. _You_ may understand those nuances but not everyone does. As I stated, there are indeed very few optimizations either at compile or runtime, but this doesn't make Python more or less "interpreted" than Java, and the reason is not that "python interprets the source code line by line" but that optimizing a very dynamic language is a difficult task.

Comment: If you give it a source file, it will first covert it to byte code (.pyc) and then it is interpreted by Cpython (or in some cases comiled Just In Time if you use PyPy). But on a basic level never (although sometime s both the interpreter and the JIT compiler do certain things) is more than one statement considered at the same time due to how hard that would be in a dynamic language

Comment: All 3 versions use compiled numpy code.  The `reshape` function calls `array` to convect the list before doing the reshape.  The reshape step takes a trivial amount of time compared the `np.array` step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. Yes — python vm does some limited optimizations. Main limitation is that python is dynamic, you can not optimize most thing ahead — unlike i.e. Java. Some implementations are more "smart" than other. For example, pypy does JIT compilations, CPython does some low-level tricks.

No — python (CPython) does not do variable inlining, reason for this is that you can run your script with `python -i non-optimized.py` and you should be able to reach all vars. Same applies to attaching debuggers.

Basically, some performance optimizations sacrificed for dynamic nature, some just not yet done in implementations.

Side note on your approaches — it's the ~same performance, reshape is super-cheap and it doesn't affect memory structure. Plus, in reality, you always want to profile your code, it's way better that theoretizing on it:

```
In [11]: %timeit my_np_array = np.reshape(my_list,(200,200))                                                                                                                                                       
1.92 ms ± 3.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit my_np_array = np.array(my_list).reshape(200,200)                                                                                                                                                  
1.92 ms ± 8.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [13]: %timeit useless_array = np.array(my_list); useful_array = useless_array.reshape(200,200)                                                                                                                  
1.92 ms ± 4.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: ok thank you for the answer! I thought `reshape` was reallocating an array, which is unlikely from what I see in your code sample.

Comment: Actually, it depends. You can read a little bit about this in doc (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape). TLDR: sometimes it's possible to reshape without memory re-alloc (shape is just metadata that tells numpy how to read memory), sometimes it's mandatory to reallocate and copy data